# Php email script failed

Tags: php, email

I have some trouble with this, Anyone know why it won't work?
I have this homepage where it uses this script for sending an email, but it won't work.
When I call that I should get an email sent, but it just runs without any error.

```
<?php 
$emailTo = 'youremail';
$siteTitle = 'SiteTitle';

//error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE); // hide all basic notices from PHP

//If the form is submitted
if(isset($_POST['submitted'])) {
    $hasError = false;
    // require a name from user
    if(trim($_POST['contactName']) === '') {
        $nameError =  'name plz!'; 
        $hasError = true;
    } else {
        $name = trim($_POST['contactName']);
    }

    // need valid email
    if(trim($_POST['email']) === '')  {
        $emailError = 'Forgot Email?';
        $hasError = true;
    } else if (!preg_match("/^[[:alnum:]][a-z0-9_.-]*@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,4}$/i", trim($_POST['email']))) {
        $emailError = 'It's not right fool';
        $hasError = true;
    } else {
        $email = trim($_POST['email']);
    }

    // we need at least some content
    if(trim($_POST['comments']) === '') {
        $commentError = 'Forgot something=';
        $hasError = true;
    } else {
        if(function_exists('stripslashes')) {
            $comments = stripslashes(trim($_POST['comments']));
        } else {
            $comments = trim($_POST['comments']);
        }
    }

    // upon no failure errors let's email now!
    if(!isset($hasError)) {

        $subject = 'New message to '.$siteTitle.' from '.$name;
        $sendCopy = trim($_POST['sendCopy']);
        $body = "Name: $name \n\nEmail: $email \n\nMessage: $comments";
        $headers = 'From: ' .' <'.$email.'>' . "\r\n" . 'Reply-To: ' . $email;

        mail($emailTo, $subject, $body, $headers);

        //Autoresponse
        $respondSubject = 'Thank you for contacting '.$siteTitle;
        $respondBody = "Your message to $siteTitle has been delivered! \n\nWe will answer back as soon as possible.";
        $respondHeaders = 'From: ' .' <'.$emailTo.'>' . "\r\n" . 'Reply-To: ' . $emailTo;

        mail($email, $respondSubject, $respondBody, $respondHeaders);

        // set our boolean completion value to TRUE
        $emailSent = true;
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 3):

Add `\` in `'`, in all occurences

```
$emailError = 'It\'s not right fool';
```

instead of

```
$emailError = 'It's not right fool';
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape any `'`s with `\` in strings that are enclosed in `'`s. For example, you need to change `$emailError = 'It's not right fool'` to `$emailError = 'It\'s not right fool'`.

The same goes for `"`s when enclosed in `"`s.

Answer (score 0):

You said it runs without any error, so it may not be a PHP error. Have you made sure that SMTP is set up properly on your sever? With the new code you just posted, are there any new errors?